# JavaScript: How can I get and use a value multiple times in an expression

Tags: javascript, expression, variable-assignment

I often find myself in a situation where I have a value followed by an expression that either uses the value multiple times or both uses the expression and returns it.  For example:

```
const errorCode = getErrorCode();
return new Error(`Error ${errorCode}: ${getErrorMessage(errorCode)}`);

const foo = getFoo();
return [getBar(foo), getBaz(foo)];  // Assume that I cannot make a function getBarAndBaz(foo)

const result = getResultOrNull();
return result
  ? result
  : getAlternative();
```

I would like to be able to avoid assigning the value to a variable so that I can convert these into one liners.

- Is there a technique or techniques that I can use to accomplish this?
- Is there a term for what I am trying to do or a name for the technique that other programming languages use to accomplish this?

If I was hypothesizing what syntax for this could look like, I could see it being something like one of the following:

```
return new Error(`Error ${errorCode}: ${getErrorMessage(errorCode)}`), where errorCode = getErrorCode();

return (getFoo(), getBar()) -> { foo: $1, bar: $2, baz: getBaz($1, $2)};
```

Both of these ideas seem similar to an immediately invoked function expressions (IIFE) except that the arguments are calculated rather than being passed in.  Therefore, I could use an IIFE with either default values or a closure:

```
(
  (foo = getFoo(), bar = getBar()) => ({ foo, bar, baz: getBaz(foo, bar)})
)()

(
  () => {
    const foo = getFoo();
    const bar = getBar();
    return (
      () => ({ foo, bar, baz: getBaz(foo, bar) })
    )();
  }
)()
```

However, these both seem a little messy.

I could use a do expression (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions):

```
do {
  const foo = getFoo();
  const bar = getBar();
  { foo, bar, baz: getBaz(foo, bar) };
};
```

However, do expressions are not yet part of JavaScript and it would be nice to find an alternative that is truly a one liner.

Comment: What is your motivation behind such a solution? Is it just by means of convenience or do you want to keep the variable names out of the current namespace?

Comment: Just as a means of convenience.  Particularly in a situation where the code would be cleaner or easier to write using an expression/one liner.  For example, it is easier to use Lodash's chain function to compose several steps if each step is an expression/single line.  Another example would be higher order functions like map which are often easier to read if the function is a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of one liner, although ugly of course:

```
function getFoo() {
  return 'FOO';
}
function getBar() {
  return 'BAR';
}
function getBaz(...args) {
  return args;
}

let result;

if (1) { let foo = getFoo(); let bar = getBar(); result = { foo, bar, baz: getBaz(foo, bar) };}

console.log(result);

// { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR', baz: [ 'FOO', 'BAR' ] }
```